# Computing a "moving sum of counts" on a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, counting, numpy-ndarray

I have the following arrays:

```
# input
In [77]: arr = np.array([23, 45, 23, 0, 12, 45, 45])

# result
In [78]: res = np.zeros_like(arr)
```

Now, I want to compute a *moving sum* of unique elements and store it in the `res` array.

Concretely, `res` array should be:

```
In [79]: res
Out[79]: array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3])
```

---

> [23, 45, 23, 0, 12, 45, 45]
>      [1,    1,    2,    1,   1,    2,    3]

We start counting each element and increment the *count* if an element re-appears, until we reach end of the array. This element specific counts should be returned as result.

---

How should we do achieve this using NumPy built-in functions? I tried using `numpy.bincount` but it gives undesired results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure you'll find a builtin, so here is a homebrew using argsort.

```
def running_count(arr):
    idx = arr.argsort(kind='mergesort')
    sarr = arr[idx]
    neq = np.where(sarr[1:] != sarr[:-1])[0] + 1
    run = np.ones(arr.shape, int)
    run[neq[0]] -= neq[0]
    run[neq[1:]] -= np.diff(neq)
    res = np.empty_like(run)
    res[idx] = run.cumsum()
    return res
```

For example:

```
>>> running_count(arr)
array([1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3])
>>> running_count(np.array(list("xabaaybeeetz")))
array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1])
```

Explainer:

We first sort using argsort because we need indices to go back to original order in the end. Here it is important to have a stable sort, hence the use of the slow mergesort.

Once the elements are sorted the running counts will form a "saw tooth" pattern. The vectorized way to create this is to observe that the diff of a saw tooth has "jump" values where a new tooth starts and ones everywhere else. So that is staight-forward to construct.